# the space between the section title and the page margin is too much

Tags: spacing, header-footer

I face a large space between the start edge of the page and the section, please forgive me as I am new user for Latex.

The problem is the distance from the paper's edge to the text body is too large

Comment: Which picture are you referring to here? Please include an image, even if it's just the URL to the image. Those with [edit privileges](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) will re-embed the image. If possible, also include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that clearly shows your current setup. This should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The question is still rather vague.  What documentclass are you using?  The appropriate answer will depend on that and other information about your set up.  Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what picture you are referring to, but probably adding something like

```
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
```

in your preamble might help you.

Change `-1in` and `1in` (in = inch) to whatever you need.

Also see [LaTeX/Page Layout](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) for more info about page layout.

Comment: I don't think it's a good thing to suggest changing `\voffset`.

Comment: @egreg You can suggest something better

Comment: @karlkoeller: I good suggestion would be to wait for the OP to clarify what "the picture" means.

Comment: @Werner This is a good point... I'll delete the answer if it is unuseful...

Comment: Oh, I can not believe, it is working, it is very good, now I can understand the [link}(http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) by the help of 
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
really very good answer. I spent more than 2 days to solve this problem, thank you very much again @karlkoeller.

Comment: @Montadar: your question has been marked as unclear because you talked about a picture but you didn't post anything in your question. You can edit your question and post a link to the picture you've mentioned.

Comment: because when I try to upload a picture, it asks me for reputations, but I do not have enough number of reputations. I am so sorry but however, your answer was very clear and it solved my problem.

Comment: However, I can explain more here,

Comment: @Montadar now you have enough reputation to post your image and remove the "unclear" mark from this question.